# What is the best way to update a table column based on a result of a sql select query C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-update

The original query :

```
with Tr As (
  SELECT
    DocDtls.Warehouse,
    Transactions.Code,
    DocDtls.zDate,
    Transactions.ID,
    Transactions.QtyIn,
    Transactions.QtyOut,
    Transactions.BalanceAfter
  FROM
    DocDtls
    INNER JOIN Transactions ON DocDtls.[PrimDocNum] = Transactions.[DocNum]
),
formatted_tr as (
  select
    ID,
    Code,
    QtyIn,
    QtyOut,
    BalanceAfter,
    LAG(BalanceAfter, 1, 0) Over (
      partition by Warehouse,
      Code
      order by
        Code,zDate,ID
    ) Prev_BlncAfter
  from
    Tr
  )
select ID,Code,QtyIn,QtyOut,BalanceAfter
,SUM(Prev_BlncAfter + QtyIn)-QtyOut As NewBlncAfter
 from formatted_tr
 group by ID,Code,QtyIn,QtyOut,BalanceAfter;
;
```

Explaining the idea :
Let's say that the query returns all transactions of Item `X` and there are 10 rows as result , I need to loop through all 10 rows and SET `BalanceAfter`( for the first transaction `QtyIn`-`QtyOut` , Any other transaction `(PreviousBalanceAfter`+`QtyIn)`-`QtyOut`) And so on .

What I've tried :
I tried to put the query result in a `Datatable` then filter it one more time using `DataView` to get the `NewBlncAfter` of the `DataGridView` current row ID  only so the `Dataview` only have one row and save it in a variable - Working well so far - when I try to loop through all rows in my `DataGridview` and update BalanceAfter I got :

> Must Declare Scalar Variable @Newblnc

You can find the whole code in here :
[My Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72331813/why-my-method-is-throwing-this-error-must-declare-scalar-variable-newblnc-c-s)

So Is there a direct way to update all transactions BalanceAfter to equal

EDIT #1 : I used @Charliface query and the result was :

[image]

I used the old query to compare the results , The `BalanceAfter` should equal `NewBlncAfter` in every row .

Edit #2 : Using `SUM` instead of `LAG` causing wrong calculation and if I used the query more than once the result in `BalanceAfter` is multiplied

```
ID  Code    QtyIn   QtyOut  BalanceAfter
9   100001  20000   0        20000
14  100001  0      6000      40000
21  100001  3500    0        60000
24  100001  0      3000      80000
```

The main idea and the desired result for example :

```
ID  Code    QtyIn   QtyOut  BalanceAfter
9   100001  20000   0        20000
14  100001  0      6000      14000
21  100001  3500    0        17500
24  100001  0      3000      14500
```

The formula is :
for the first transaction `QtyIn`-`QtyOut` , Any other transaction `(PreviousBalanceAfter`+`QtyIn)`-`QtyOut` And so on .

Comment: Based on the series of questions you've asked, I have to suggest you step back. Why does C# need to get in the middle, and update a table based on the result of a query? Can't the query do that without shuffling some scalar value back and forth into C#? What do the extra round trips gain you, other than additional points of failure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Something felt wrong so I asked for your opinion , Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I see no reason at all to pull all this data into C# only to then update row-by-row (which is highly inefficient). You can do this in a single batch update.

It's not quite clear what result you want, but it seems you want to just assign a running `SUM` calculation, rather than `LAG`.

Furthermore:

- The second CTE is unnecessary and can be collapsed into the first.
- Partitioning and ordering by the same column in an `OVER` makes no sense.
- The final `GROUP BY` also makes no sense and appears unnecessary, as you are grouping by a primary key.

```sql
WITH Tr AS (
  SELECT
    d.Warehouse,
    t.Code,
    d.zDate,
    t.ID,
    t.QtyIn,
    t.QtyOut,
    t.BalanceAfter,
    SUM(t.QtyIn - t.QtyOut) OVER (
      PARTITION BY d.Warehouse, t.Code
      ORDER BY d.zDate, t.ID
      ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
    ) BlncAfter
  FROM
    DocDtls d
    INNER JOIN Transactions t ON d.PrimDocNum = t.DocNum
  WHERE t.Code = @VariableCode
)
UPDATE Tr
SET BalanceAfter = BlncAfter;
```

One final point: why bother storing this information in a new column at all? Why not just calculate it when you need to, using `SUM OVER`?

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply , I learned a lot from it , About your final point it will be easier in the future with reports and 10,000+ records I think it will be faster if the value already stored .

Comment: About the result I used your query but the result isn't accurate , The second row calculated as if the `Prev_Blnc` = 0 which not true , Please have a look on the image in EDIT#1.

Comment: Looks like you want `SUM` rather than `LAG`, see edit

Comment: Unfortunately using sum caused wrong calculation , I made a demo on Edit#2 please have a look , Sorry for bothering you .

Comment: Sample data and expected results do help, as you see. You need `SUM(t.QtyIn - t.QtyOut)` I think

Comment: `I think it will be faster if the value already stored` - this is premature optimization. Solve that problem _when you have that problem_.

Comment: ...otherwise, it's redundant storage, additional computations, and then having to keep _all_ the rows updated when _any_ row is updated. For nothing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for advice Noted , All will be clear to me when I finish this system then I will go back for developing and increase efficiency  .

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you so much It's fast and efficient , Exactly what I need , Sorry for troubling you with so many weaknesses .